# Clipboard data won't get pasted

Tags: winapi, clipboard

I'm tryng to load into and paste data from the clipboard like this:

```
int main() {

    Sleep(3000);

    char buf[] = "Hello33";

    HWND hwnd = GetActiveWindow();

    if (OpenClipboard(hwnd)) {
        EmptyClipboard();
        HGLOBAL hClipboardData;
        hClipboardData = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_DDESHARE, BUFLEN);
        char * pchData;
        pchData = (char*) GlobalLock(hClipboardData);
        strcpy(pchData, LPCSTR(buf));
        GlobalUnlock(hClipboardData);
        SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hClipboardData);
        CloseClipboard();

        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_PASTE, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Starting the program, then open text editor, text editor is the top window and no text is pasted. If I do the paste command `Ctrl-V` I got `Hello33` into the text area.

Comment: `GetActiveWindow` probably returns `NULL` when called from a command line application. It returns the active window of the calling thread. You probably meant to call [GetForegroundWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633505.aspx) instead. Either way, you get a top-level window. That's usually not a window that processes a `WM_PASTE` message.

Comment: Irrespective of the bugs in your code, the clipboard belongs to the user. Don't use it without the user's consent. If you want to automate another application, use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx) instead.

Comment: If a null HWND is passed to `OpenClipboard()` (such as if `GetActivewindow()` fails), `SetClipboardData()` will fail. This is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649048.aspx) behavior: "*If an application calls **OpenClipboard** with hwnd set to **NULL**, **EmptyClipboard** sets the clipboard owner to **NULL**; this causes **SetClipboardData** to fail.*"  You can't open the clipboard using an HWND that you do not already own.

Answer (score 0):

GetActiveWindow returns the main window not the child window

you should try GetFocus();

but even this will not work, be cause it is in an other thread that belong to other process.

to resolve that, call  [AttachThreadInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

finally  i suggest to drop all of this, and try FindWindow instead and send message directly to the Edit Box, by using [SendDlgItemMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645515%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)